# Can NoClassDefFoundError be thrown AFTER the class has been loaded/used?

Tags: java, web-applications, noclassdeffounderror

The context is this: I have class with all static methods and a static initialize block. This class is part of a web application, which is packed as a war and deployed inside WebSphere 10.

There are situations where other classes in the war try to call methods on this class, only to get a NoClassDefFoundError. What I find strange is that, I can see from the logs that the class's methods and such have already been called multiple times, successfully, but all of a sudden, an identical (previously successful) method call will presently generate a NoClassDefFoundError. At this point any future such calls to the class's static methods will generate that error (until the WebSpehere container is restarted or the war is redeployed).

What puzzles me is why the class seems to work for a while before throwing the NoClassDefFoundError. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) on this exception says:

*The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.*

So my question is,how come a class is usable for a while, clearly responding to calls to its static methods and then throw NoClassDefFoundError?

Comment: I would have a look into custom class loaders / agents you are using in your web app. If the class loader which loaded the class is not part of the loader hierarchy anymore (e.g if you are using custom class loaders and have some fault in there), then those errors can occur.

Comment: @Matthias it's just a plain WebSphere 10.3.3, no customization done to its classloaders or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` its not `ClassNotFoundException`. it can occur when:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of **creating a new instance using the new expression**) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.

My experience shows that if there an exception in static initializer block, this exception can be thrown too.

[Why NoClassDefFoundError caused by static field initialization failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352215/java-why-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-caused-by-static-field-initializ-failur)

Comment: Yes, but my question is: how is it possible to get into a NoClassDefFoundError situation even AFTER the class's static init block successful execution and even some successful static method calls on that class. Aren't we past that as this point, isn't the class definition successfully found and loaded already?

Comment: @ShivanDragon I see now. You're right i miss understood your question at first. Maybe you have some classloader issues? I'm not familiar with WebSphere at all. take a look on this article maybe you can find something useful http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html

Comment: Thanks, it's pretty useful, though the last sentence made me kind of sad: "Please note that Java EE containers such as Oracle Weblogic have mechanisms to override this default class loader delegation behavior. I will get back to this in the future articles." :(((

Comment: @ShivanDragon Maybe you should go through next parts then(http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2012/06/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to_15.html, http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2012/07/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html, http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2012/08/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-parent.html )in fourth part of this article i found note that you can run JVM in verbose mode which shows you classloader info, maybe this is the way to resolve this