# JVM can't find classes after switching network access point

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

Instead of a long narrative, I'm going to simply list the steps that tend to cause unusual class loading problems for the JVM.

- 0) User brings their laptop to the conference room for testing. There they will connect to our corporate network using WI-FI.
- 1) User starts our Java Swing based application, which communicates with an Oracle backend using JDBC.
- 2) Testing goes fine; application works as expected, no problems with the JVM.
- 3) User leaves the app running, and takes the laptop back to their desk and plugs it into the docking station (changes network access point).
- 4) User tries to shutdown the application, but now every class needed throws an "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError".

This is not the usual case of not deploying libraries in the class path. The same actions taken while still connected to WI-FI will not throw the exception.

I've searched quite a bit to see if anyone has had similar problems. The closest I've come is this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289205/can-noclassdeffounderror-be-thrown-after-the-class-has-been-loaded-used).

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect it swallows actual exception and raising one internally instead

Comment: What happens when the same user **starts** the application at their desk?  Do you have anything that relies on a computer keeping its IP address?

Comment: No, there's nothing that keeps an IP address. The database access resolves the host name with each access. Each query opens and closes a connection to the DB. No one has experienced this problem from their desk; the problem only seems to occur when moving from one access point to another.