# NoClassDefFoundError on Non-static class with private constructor

Tags: java, constructor, static, private

I have a Java class that has a private constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
  private static final MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

  private MyClass() {}

  public static MyClass getInstance() {
    return myClass;
  }
}
```

This class is being used in the application like this:

```
MyClass myClass = MyClass.getInstance();
```

The whole application is also exported as a JAR and used in another application.

When I try to do the same in another application (Where its being invoked from a JAR) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.example.MyClass
```

I am not sure if this is the required behavior for a class with a ***private constructor***, or is there something else wrong with it?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352215/why-noclassdeffounderror-caused-by-static-field-initialization-failure for more information about this, particularly the answers by users trutheality and irreputable.

Comment: Top-level classes cannot be `static`. What is meant here by a "non-static" class? The term is meaningless in a Java sense.

Comment: What is the exact command line you use "in another application" that's supposed to use the JAR?

Comment: @LewBloch I just wanted to highlight that as it has a private constructor.

Comment: Okay, then just say that. "Static class" has a meaning, and it doesn't apply to top-level classes, and thus not to your question, which has nothing to do with static classes.

Comment: @LewBloch What do you mean by command line? In my other application I am just using Java code to refer that class.

Comment: @LewBloch okay, will keep in mind the next time.

Comment: Command line: the text of the command used to run a program. It's a standard term. Google is your friend.

Comment: I didn't know in which context you used that term, I run the application through an IDE, IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

Your error has nothing to do with static-ness or your constructor. From the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/):

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found. The searched-for class
>   definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled,
>   but the definition can no longer be found.

NoClassDefFoundError means the class definition is unavailable when you're trying to run your program. This is some kind of path error - either this class is not in the exported jar or it's not being included on the classpath when it's being run.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have correct included the JAR in the classpath of the second application?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I am invoking other classes and their methods from the same jar file.

Comment: Have you checked the JAR file to ensure it contains the class of interest?

Comment: @LewBloch Yes, it does contain that class!

Comment: @nullpointer The problem you're having isn't related to using a Singleton with a private constructor.  This is definitely a class path issue.  After all, your code compiles correctly, which means the compiler can find the class.  Try to determine the difference between what the compiler is using versus your runtime test.  Are you using an IDE to do this?  If so, which?

Comment: @LukasBradley I am using IntelliJ, here's another thing: Before this I got  error that a certain class was missing (being used in the JAR and not in my current project). That was a compile time error, not runtime. I added that library (Hibernate) in my gradle file, and now getting this error. Could you relate the two?

Comment: @LukasBradley Although I added that as a runtime dependency.

Comment: Tell us more about how you are trying to execute the code.  Are you also doing this in IntelliJ?  Command line?

Comment: @LukasBradley I added hibernate as a compile dependency in my gradle file, and it solved the issue! Its strange that when I add it as a runtime, it only gets resolved the first time and not the subsequent turns, which caused this whole topic! Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

**NoClassDefFoundError** Occurs when JVM tries to load a particular class that is the part of your code execution (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating an instance using the new keyword) and that class is not present in your classpath but was present at compile time because in order to execute your program you need to compile it and if you are trying use a class which is not present compiler will raise compilation error.