# ClassNotFoundException when trying to use IMPS with JADE in Java

Tags: java, cmd, agents-jade

When trying to run imps using jade in the cmd I get this error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jade.core.migration.InterPlatformMobilityService" but when I run it in netbeans it runs properly with no error.

I have set the Class Path to the same path that netbeans is using but have had no luck. I unzipped the imps folder provided by jade using jar -xvm.

Here is what I try to run

```
java jade.Boot -port 2000 -gui -accept-foreign-agents true -services jade.core.mobility.AgentMobilityService;jade.core.migration.InterPlatformMobilityService;jade.core.event.NotificationService
```

Here is the class path I get from echo %CLASSPATH%

```
C:\...\javaLibs\jade\lib\jade.jar; C:\...\javaLibs\jade\lib\jadeTools.jar; C:\...\javaLibs\jade\lib\http.jar; C:\...\javaLibs\jade\lib\commons-codec\commons-codec-1.3.jar; C:\...\javaLibs\jade\add-ons\ipms\lib\migration.jar;
```

Here is the error

```
WARNING: Exception initializing service jade.core.migration.InterPlatformMobilityService
jade.core.ServiceException: An error occurred during service activation - Caused by:  jade.core.migration.InterPlatformMobilityService
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.startService(AgentContainerImpl.java:1169)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.initAdditionalServices(AgentContainerImpl.java:450)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.startNode(AgentContainerImpl.java:389)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:502)
        at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:159)
        at jade.Boot.main(Boot.java:89)
Nested Exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jade.core.migration.InterPlatformMobilityService
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:332)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.startService(AgentContainerImpl.java:1153)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.initAdditionalServices(AgentContainerImpl.java:450)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.startNode(AgentContainerImpl.java:389)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:502)
        at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:159)
        at jade.Boot.main(Boot.java:89)
```

This should be able to run the JADE gui with IMPS to mobilize agents

Comment: One potential cause is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352215/why-noclassdeffounderror-caused-by-static-field-initialization-failure

Comment: I am using a precompiled .jar from the jade ipms add on, it looks like that thread focuses on .jar files that are not precompiled

Comment: try to add classpath explicitly. `java -classpath "C:\...\javaLibs\jade\lib\jade.jar;C:\...\javaLibs\jade\lib\jadeTools.jar;C:\...\javaLibs\jade\lib\http.jar;C:\...\javaLibs\jade\lib\commons-codec\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\...\javaLibs\jade\add-ons\ipms\lib\migration.jar" jade.Boot -port 2000 -gui -accept-foreign-agents true -services jade.core.mobility.AgentMobilityService;jade.core.migration.InterPlatformMobilityService;jade.core.event.NotificationService`